# NServiceBus gateway setup and configuration

Tags: nservicebus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NserviceBus Gateway Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518574/nservicebus-gateway-sample)

I'm looking for a step by step example of how to setup and configure the gateway. I'm trying to investigate how we might use this on one of our projects and I'm struggling to find anything other than a high level overview.

This is just conceptual at this point but the likely hood is the we will be using NSB to synchronise data between 2 or more remote sites. It is possible that these may end up as part of the same VPN but it is more likely that one or more won't and that we will need to use the http gateway for cross site communication.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.