# NserviceBus Gateway Sample

Tags: nservicebus, gateway

Has anyone managed to get the NServiceBus Gateway component to work?
The sample in v3.0 does not work out of the box like other samples.

A step by step guide or code sample will be helpful to get this component working.

Thanks

Comment: I would try 2.5 for now, 3.0 is currently under work and may not be completely stable.

Comment: @Adam 2.5 Does not have a code sample for Gateway.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed some issues and verified that the Gateway sample in 3.0 runs ok just by hitting F5.
Please update to the latest version and give it a try.

Comment: Hello,   I just tried the gateway sample and it does not work with the main branch of the code.  Could you provide me a hint?

Comment: We haven't moved it to the master yet, please use the develop branch

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund it is running OK after pressing F5 but the messages sent from the headquarters are not received at the sites(I am running everything locally). Even the http://localhost/Headquarter/ requests results in a 404 error. Am I missing any configuration settings?

Comment: Seems like we renamed the profile that starts the gateway and forgot to update the sample. Go into properties-> debug in the headquarter project and change the cmdline from RunGateway to MultiSite. Thanks!

Comment: You need to do this for SiteA as well. This has now been fixed on the dev branch.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample of NServiceBus Gateway being used on version v3.0:

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/master/Samples/Gateway